# Вопрос по header Location

Tags: php

Можно ли определить было ли перенаправление без записи сессии и т.п.? Типа как POST запрос:

```
if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
  echo 'запрос выполнен';
}
else
{
  echo 'запрос не выполнен';
}
```

Comment: Можно посмотреть $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']

Comment: К стате идея, если сверять так $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] существует только когда идет переход по ссылке а не редирект через header('Location:...');

Comment: Уже протестил, понял)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать следующим образом:
index.php:

```
header('Location:test.php?ref=1');
```

test.php:

```
if ((isset($_GET['ref']) && ($_GET['ref']=='1')){
    echo 'Redirect from index.php';
} else {
    echo 'Without redirect';
}
```

Если переход по ссылке, то можно смотреть значение $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

Comment: Суть в том что $_GET использоваться не должно!

Comment: ну а по другому через header никак. Можно делать через ajax post запрос и параметром передавать что было перенаправление.

Comment: Можно просто записать ссессию, перенаправить и после перенаправления сверить сессию. Просто было интересно может ли обрабатываться перенаправление каким то методом.

Всем спасибо.